# Entity Framework not persisting complex entity changes on SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**Update:** I was being an idiot. Everything was being persisted to disk, but `@Html.EditorFor(x => ...)` was not showing the values.

---

A complex Entity Framework object's non-virtual sub-properties are not being updated after I call `db.SaveChanges();` despite explicitly telling Entity framework that the instance has changed with:

```
db.Entry(myComplexEntity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

Flat properties in the entity are being updated, but none of the (non-virtual) objects inside the object are, e.g. the values in `Step1`:

```
public class Wizard
{
    [Key]
    public Guid WizardId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public Step1 Step1 { get; set; }
    // ... 
    public Step5 Step5 { get; set; }

    public Wizard()
    {
        Step1 = new Step1();
        // ...
        Step5 = new Step5();
    }
}
```

I have confirmed the values in `input` are being bound correctly, but despite being explicitly set, the values are not being saved to the database. Here is how I am setting the values:

```
using (var db = new MyDataContext())
{
    wizard = db.Wizards.First(x => x.WizardId == id);

    wizard.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now; // this is being saved to the DB

    // The following properties are not persisted to the database:
    wizard.Step1.Capacity = input.Capacity;
    wizard.Step1.Color = input.Color;
    wizard.Step1.Conditions = input.Conditions;
    wizard.Step1.SerialNumber = input.SerialNumber;
    wizard.Step1.Model = input.Model;

    db.Entry(wizard).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Why are my complex object's non-virtual sub-properties' values not being saved? Even more puzzling, one of the simple "step" objects are persisting to disk, but most are not.

Comment: I take it you are using code first? What does the database tables look like? Are the steps marked as `[ComplexType]`?

Comment: You need to include `Step1` when you retrieve the `wizard`, or make it `virtual` so that it will be lazy loaded. Otherwise the context doesn't know about it and can't detect any changes that should be saved

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
public Step1 Step1 { get; set; }
```

To this (in order to create a foreign key in your model):

```
public int Step1Id {get;set;}
public virtual Step1 Step1 { get; set; }
```

And I always use something like this:

```
Step1 s1 = new Step1();
// ... assign values here ...
db.Step1s.Add(s1);
db.SaveChanges();

wizard.Step1Id = s1.Id;
db.SaveChanges();
```